# What is speed of email?

Tags: communication, signal

I want to know how can we calculate speed of email. I guess that won't be same as speed of electricity or baud rate.

I think it gets more complicated considering data doesn't travel in just one medium like only coaxial or only wireless.

Does it matter how far point A is from point B?

I say email, but I think it applies to information on network in general.

Comment: How long is a piece of string ?

Comment: @PaulR, 3 units.

Comment: @avakar: you've rounded down to the nearest whole number I see !

Comment: SuperUser.com fodder methinks.  Migration please?

Comment: The sound of one dog barking.

Comment: The answer or range of answers can be calculated accurately if all parameters are known but in a network such as the internet there are so many unknown and uncontrollable variables involved that it is completely impossible to give a general answer.

Comment: It's pretty fast, but not really super fast, sometimes slow, every once in a while really slow, but not too often.

Comment: @Majenko This is more of a corporate IT question then it is about personal PC use, so SuperUser probably isn't the best place. In fact, in many places this is an electrical engineering topic (at least it was at my university), but it doesn't fall into the scope of our site.

Comment: If someone wanted to get technical on this it could be on-topic here under "a communication scheme", thoughts?

Answer (score 6):

Email doesn't just go from point A to point B.

It hops along a network path between nodes.

Some of these nodes (routers) will just forward the network traffic to the next node.

Some of the nodes (email servers) will store the email in a queue for dissemination to the next hop.

It is impossible to predict the length of time an email will take to get from point A to point B as there are too many unknown variables.

You can examine the contents of an email to see when it was sent, and when each email server received it and sent it on (Received: headers).

You can use tools like "traceroute" to examine the network path between two points to see how long packets take to get through the network.

Comment: +1, the time the email spends en route is dominated by the time it spends in queues.

Comment: Most major delays in email are from short-term failures that result in retries after a long delay. These delays could be 4 hours, 12 hours, 24 hours, etc. Well, that and horribly misconfigured/overloaded email servers.

Comment: I once had an email arrive almost a year after it was sent.  I was a bit surprised it arrived at all, but if I recall it spent the vast majority of that time on a server just before mine, whose name I didn't recognize.  My guess would be that a server was unexpectedly taken off-line for a year, but when it returned it delivered the mail in transit.

Answer (score -1):

Simple, the speed of email is 299792458 m / s, but, as indicated below, only in vacuum. otherwise, its typically the speed of [electricity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_electricity).

Comment: But email does not travel in a vacuum !

Comment: It used to be 360 kB per unit. Generally it may not travel, as you adumbrate, at the speed of write.

Comment: @PaulR It does if you have a dyson with a *digital* motor! ;)

Comment: I tried using a Dyson for email but I'm afraid it just sucked.

Comment: The speed of email changes based off of where it is at in the chain... copper between you and your ISP, probably mostly fiber between ISPs, a few bits of silicon, and it might even have a few other mediums thrown in there.

Comment: @nomennescio, approximating delays on communications is a useful task but often the line delay is a much smaller part compared to the raw number and processing time of packets to complete a task like sending an email.

Comment: No email does not travel at speed of light...the speed is dictated by the speed of the Telecom link as well as the processing speed of intermediate routers...as someone said above you can do trace route (tracert) in command prompt to determine the speed...